How to "Evaluate" column of a table within a COUNTIFS()
I have a table (real table, not just looking like one) with multiple columns, one called Date Created and the contents are in the format, e.g.,  3. Juni 2023 16:09:12 MESZ.
My goal is to count all entries in column artifact type meeting specific criteria created  after a date given in form dd.mm.yyyy to, lets say, get the artifacts created this week.
I get the desired result by adding a colum column1 to table1 with formula =DATEVALUE(LEFT([@[Date Created]];LEN([@[Date Created]])-13)) in combination with =SUM(COUNTIFS(Tabelle1[Artifact Type];{"type1";"type3";"type xy"};Tabelle1[column1];">="&DATEVALUE("14.8.2024"))) in the desired cell.
However, how do I directly get the same result without the step of adding columns? I have no idea how to "evaluate/transform" the entries in Date Created "on the fly".
I am using MS Office 2019 without the possibility of using macros.

Try: =SUMPRODUCT((Tabelle1[Artifact Type]={"type1";"type3";"type xy"})*(DATEVALUE(LEFT([@[Date Created]];LEN([@[Date Created]])-13))>=DATE(2024;8;14)))

@Rory Your Suggestion does not work as I have to add Tabelle1 in front of each referenced cell and it only accepts only one argument for the artifact type. When I use the given ones I get a #N/A-error.

@clme What if you remove @ symbols?

@bugdrown Sorry, still #N/A. The ugly brute force method would be to calculate the sumproduct 3 times, with summing their results. When I do want to perform the same thing but for, e.g., five different artifacts it gets really ugly really fast with a pain in the back to maintain...

You might.be able to do cell transformations and return an aggregate value (e.g., SUM) using Power Query.

It's probably a regional settings issue. I don't know what you use to separate array elements - perhaps commas? =SUMPRODUCT((Tabelle1[Artifact Type]={"type1","type3","type xy"})*(DATEVALUE(LEFT(Tabelle1[@[Date Created]];LEN(Tabelle1[@[Date Created]])-13))>=DATE(2024;8;14)))

Hey Rory, I think it does not stem from regional settings since I have no issues with the given formulas in the original post. Since I am able to read the desired values within the tool the data stems from (although quite annoying) I gave up on the excel approach as the time spent is not worth the time saved in the results. And a solution with "translating tables" (lets say Table 2 converting data from table 3 and table 1 reading results from table 2) is in my opinion, error prone and a "dirty hack". Maybe my way of thinking using python is in the way
